# MySQL JOIN table based on MAX(date) in main table, and MAX(id) in joined table with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, join, limit

If the title didn't make any sense here's what I need to do in a nut shell.. I need to select the most recent X amount of records "by date" in the main table, then join the data that belongs to those records by selecting the most recent record "by id" in the joined table..

Here's some sample outputs..

table: lead_unique (only unique ssn's in this table)

```
+-----------+--------------+
| ssn       | created_date |
+-----------+--------------+
| 111111111 | 2015-03-01   |
| 999999999 | 2015-03-03   |
| 555555555 | 2015-02-08   |
+-----------+--------------+
```

table: lead_data

```
+----+-----------+-------+----------------+-------------+-------+-------+
| id | ssn       | name  | address        | city        | state | zip   |
+----+-----------+-------+----------------+-------------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 111111111 | Bob1  | 1234 Test Ln   | Mound       | CA    | 55555 |
|  2 | 111111111 | Bob2  | 1234 Test Ln   | Mound       | CA    | 55555 |
|  3 | 999999999 | Jane1 | 5432 Lola Blvd | Patton      | NJ    | 33333 |
|  4 | 999999999 | Jane2 | 5432 Lola Blvd | Patton      | NJ    | 33333 |
|  5 | 555555555 | Jack1 | 832 92nd Ave N | Bright View | AL    | 88888 |
|  6 | 999999999 | Jane3 | 5432 Lola Blvd | Patton      | NJ    | 33333 |
+----+-----------+-------+----------------+-------------+-------+-------+
```

desired output (can be asc/desc date column, don't matter)

```
+--------------+-----------+-------+
| created_date | ssn       | name  |
+--------------+-----------+-------+
| 2015-03-03   | 999999999 | Jane3 |
| 2015-03-01   | 111111111 | Bob2  |
| 2015-02-08   | 555555555 | Jack1 |
+--------------+-----------+-------+
```

desired output (limit 2)

```
+--------------+-----------+-------+
| created_date | ssn       | name  |
+--------------+-----------+-------+
| 2015-03-03   | 999999999 | Jane3 |
| 2015-03-01   | 111111111 | Bob2  |
+--------------+-----------+-------+
```

Query might be something like the following but I also may be wayyy off since I'm here asking for help and having no luck..

```
SELECT   
    lead_unique.created_date, 
    lead_unique.ssn,
    lead_data.name
FROM      
    lead_unique
JOIN      
    (
        SELECT    
            ...
        FROM      
            lead_data
        ...
    ) lead_data 
        ...
...
LIMIT 2
```

I have only used stack overflow once before so if there's anything more I can add to be helpful please let me know! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be inclined to use a correlated subquery for the data piece -- your question only mentions one column:

```
select u.created_date, u.ssn,
       (select d.name
        from lead_data d
        where d.ssn = u.ssn
        order by d.id desc
        limit 1
       ) as name
from lead_unique u
order by u.created_date desc
limit 2;
```

Actually, for performance reasons, I would put the unique component in a subquery:

```
select u.created_date, u.ssn,
       (select d.name
        from lead_data d
        where d.ssn = u.ssn
        order by d.id desc
        limit 1
       ) as name
from (select u.*
      from lead_unique u
      order by u.created_date desc
      limit 2
     ) u;
```

EDIT:

Even with multiple columns, the most performant method might still be to use subqueries:

```
select created_date, ssn, d.*
from (select u.created_date, u.ssn,
             (select d.id
              from lead_data d
              where d.ssn = u.ssn
              order by d.id desc
              limit 1
             ) as id
      from (select u.*
            from lead_unique u
            order by u.created_date desc
            limit 2
           ) u
     ) u join
     lead_data d
     on u.id = d.id;
```

By the way, if performance is an issue, you want the following indexes:  `lead_unique(created_date)` and `lead_data(id)`.  This should be pretty fast with those two indexes.

Comment: The lead_data table was kept simple so I only added one extra column of data (name), but in reality there are many more data columns in the table so the query would need to be able to handle unlimited more columns.. Output could be "created_date, ssn, name, address, city, state, zip....etc..".

Comment: Hey there.. I got that last query to work for what I needed.. Thank you very much! I did have indexes on those fields and the query is pretty fast too.. The actual tables are quite large.. 8 million in one and almost 300 million in the lead data table.. Awesome! Now to figure out how to accept this answer..