# How to approach query - most efficient way to show most recent comment from threads

Tags: mysql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I am not even really sure how to search for this type of question, let alone tackle solving it. Please direct me if there are keywords to use for developing such a query, and thus searching for solutions already provided.

I have two tables - threads and comments.

**thread** table

| thread_id | title | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foobar | foo |
| 2 | Barfoo | bar |

**comment** table

| comment_id | date | text | thread_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | lorem | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | ipsem | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | gypsum | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | tippy | 2 |

Use - I want to show a sidebar on the front page of a site showing the latest comments. But I only want to show the most recent comment per each thread. Meaning, I want the result to look like this:

**result**

| comment_id | text | thread_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | tippy | 2 |
| 2 | ipsem | 1 |

Can anyone kindly point me to how I might go about searching for help / keywords on this type of query and/or direct help in what mysql syntax is necessary to do this kind of query please?

Thank you

Comment: Something like this? Search terms I used were "mysql join limit max" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177721/mysql-join-table-based-on-maxdate-in-main-table-and-maxid-in-joined-table-w

Comment: This type of question is asked frequently. Usually they are tagged [tag:greatest-n-per-group]. There are many good answers posted.